# get src and other text from string with iframes

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe

From this string - 
`some alphanumeric text <iframe ... src="srcval1" ... > ... </iframe> <iframe ... src="srcval2" ... > ... </iframe> some more alphanumeric text <iframe ... src="srcval3" ... > ... </iframe>`

I want the following -
`some alphanumeric text srcval1 srcval2 some more alphanumeric text srcval3` 
using a regex

When I do `str.split(/ \<iframe[^\>]*\>[^\<]*\<\/iframe\>/).join(" ")` I lose "srcvals"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A greedy replace along the lines of this should work

```
/<iframe.*?src="(.*?)".*?<\/iframe>/\1/
```

Comment: But I dont know srcval1! It is unknown

Comment: In chrome - l.split(/<iframe.*?src="(.*?)".*?<\/iframe>/\1/)                                                 I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

Comment: You want to replace it.

Comment: l.replace("/<iframe.*?src=\"(.*?)\".*?<\/iframe>/", "$1" )

Comment: Not working, you may use this string: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/odThhIA2gUM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>fgfgdg<iframe> yoyo </iframe> uo

Comment: `String.prototype.replace` takes a RegExp object as first parameter, not a string.

Comment: I think <iframe //no src//> </iframe> is not usually the case, I will accept the answer! @Casimir - correct!